# How to create a bootable Ubuntu hard disk from an image of an Ubuntu partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, clonezilla

I had a dual boot SSD with Windows 7 (on primary) and Ubuntu 18.04 (on extended partition). I needed to delete the Windows partition so as to let Ubuntu use the entire HDD.

Since Ubuntu was on the extended partition, it was not possible to resize it. So, I created an image of the Ubuntu 18.04 partition using `clonezilla`. Then, I deleted all the existing partitions in the SSD and created a single new ext4 partition on the SSD (`sda1`).

Next I cloned the 18.04 partition image back to the new partition (`sda1`). However, I got an error message stating that it was unable to restore extended boot record into an extended partition (`sda4`) which existed in the SSD before creating the new partition table. I tried to use disk repair to fix the boot issue, but it failed to do so.

**My question is how to create a bootable ubuntu disk (in a newly formatted/partitioned SSD/HDD) from an image of an ubuntu partition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you write of extended partitions, I assume MBR with legacy BIOS boot style. There are several ways to recover from this situation.

#### "Jump-Start"

Use any tool to boot into the "dead" system. I recommend [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) for ease of use.

From within the system, execute `sudo grub-install /dev/yoursystemdisk` and `sudo update-grub` and you are done.

#### External GRUB Install

Boot a live Linux. Mount the "dead" Linux file-system (I assume `/mnt`). From the live Linux, execute `sudo grub-install --root-partition=/mnt /dev/yoursystemdisk` and `sudo grub-mkconfig /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

#### chroot

Boot a live Linux. Mount the "dead" Linux file-system. Bind `/dev`, `/sys` and `/proc` into the "dead" system. Chroot into the "dead" system, then execute the commands from the jump-start method.

Comment: Tried the method titles jump-start. Worked for me. Thanks a lot.